# WinJS intellisense not working correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, winjs

I'm having some issues (I think) with intellisense in my Win8 HTML5/JS app.

If I have the following code in a page (in the ready: function):

```
var control = element.querySelector("#rating").winControl;
```

My first question is, the .winControl property doesn't show in the intellisense, but from searching the web this appears to be the expected behaviour (given the difficulties in providing intellisense in a language like javascript)?

However, my main problem is now when I try to access properties on my control variable I get the message:

> Intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression

I have added the `/// <reference path...` etc to the base.js and ui.js in the WinJS reference but it still doesn't work.

Has anyone experienced this before? Is this the correct behaviour? What am I missing here?

Cheers

Comment: My best guess is that this is intentional. I'd imagine its pretty darn hard in the situation you've described for the intellisense engine to determine what the state of your element is prior to execution. In theory you could have changed the control on the element, etc.

Comment: I get this all the time when I try to reference namespaces/classes outside the scope of my nonruntime current html's javascript. so it works but it only works at runtime. kinda annoying but it may just be how i have my project set up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is the expected behavior in Visual Studio 2012. Currently .winControl does not show up even though it is valid at runtime.

As a workaround, you can use documentation comments to tell the JavaScript editor the type of the variable, and you can then get IntelliSense for it. Using your example above (I'll assume you want to see suggestions for the WinJS.UI.Rating control), type:

```
/// <var type="WinJS.UI.Rating"/>
var control = element.querySelector("#rating").winControl;
control.
```

And now you'll see the completion list for a Rating control.

- Jordan,  Microsoft Visual Studio PM

Comment: Thanks Jordan, that's a great tip!

Answer (score 0):

The querySelector function returns a DOM element. Since .winControl is not a standard property on a DOM element, there is no way for intellisense to present it to you as an option.

Since your 'control' variable is being assigned to an object of a type that is unknown to intellisense, it is unable to give you any help on what properties may or may not be present on the unknown object.